# Spring Hibernate getCurrentSession() delete not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am fully testing an entity on my unit test, and almost everything worked so far: create, update, list. However, when I try to delete a record, it is not getting deleted. Here is the code I am using:

```
  public void delete (Integer id) {
    // This doesnt work even though I know user is set and id is not null
    User user = find(id);
    getSession().delete(user);
    // This will work
    // Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("DELETE FROM users WHERE id = " + id);
    // query.executeUpdate();
  }    

    private Session getSession() {
      if (session == null) {        
        try {
            session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, Boolean.TRUE);
          TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(session.getSessionFactory(), new SessionHolder(session));            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            session = SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(sessionFactory, Boolean.FALSE);          
        }
      }
      return session;
    }
```

If I execute the query directly it works but using the delete() method doesnt. I think it may be related to committing the transaction but I already tried something like that and no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem with this one.

First, find() method was evicting my user model, and probably taking it out of the session.

After delete(), I also needed to session.flush()

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?