# getCurrentSession().delete fail

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

i've configured the transaction to spring like:

```
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

and add @transactional at the method of service

```
@Transactional
public boolean delete(int id) {
    return articleDao.delete(id);
}
```

and this is the delete method of dao

```
@Override
public boolean delete(T entity) {
    try {
        getSession().delete(entity);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

there is no exception but just can't delete 
i guess that transaction just dont work
because i try to delete like

```
getSession().createQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
```

and there is an exception:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

but i've configured the transaction
i've been tried for a long time, please help me

Comment: Please take a look at this [Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415621/spring-hibernate-getcurrentsession-delete-not-working)

Comment: btw if i try "getSession.beginTransaction()" first. and then "getSession().createQuery(sql).executeUpdate();"  it work